# Haskell - Uploading a file with Haskell (POST method)

Tags: haskell, servant

I want to replicate this curl command

```
curl --request POST \
'https://www.someapi.com/upload/textfile?id=someid' \
--header 'Authorization: someauthcode' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: appication/octet-stream' \
--data '{"owner":"name"}' \
--data @somefile.txt
```

Much of the coding in my project is done with Servant DSL so I though something like this should be the ideal solution

```
baseURL = BaseUrl Https "www.someapi.com" 443 ""

uploadAPI :: Proxy Upload                                                                                                    
uploadAPI = Proxy   

type Upload = "upload" :> ... :> ReqBody '[OctetStream] ByteString :> Post '[OctetStream] ()

uploadImage :: Proxy Upload
uploadImage = Proxy
```

But that doesn't work.

So I want to ask, what would be the best alternative?

Edit: Forgot to add error -

```
• No instance for (MimeUnrender OctetStream ())                                                                              
    arising from a use of ‘client’                                                                                           
• In the expression: client uploadAPI                                                                                        
  In an equation for ‘uploadImage’: uploadImage = client uploadAPI                                                           
   |
```

Comment: Can you specify what is not working?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the error message. Fixed it

Comment: The code you show doesn't use `client` at all.  Why is it in the error message?

Comment: Sorry I was diagnosing it from ghci. The `client` is from `Servant.Client` applied on `uploadAPI` function.